# how to make a new array from specific property within each original array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, mapping, spread-syntax

I have an array of items with this structure:

```
originalArray = [
  {
    product: { price: 10},
    shipping: {...}
  },
  {
    product: {price: 20},
    shipping: {...},
  }
]
```

I want to make a new array that is just the products from each original array item, like:

```
[ {price: 10}, {price: 20} ]
```

Using javascript (es6/2015 is fine)

What's the fastest way to do this? Is there any way to do it without a loop / map? The amount of items in the array will be dynamic / I will not know how many there might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to just map it

```js
var originalArray = [{
    product: {
      price: 10
    },
    shipping: {}
  },
  {
    product: {
      price: 20
    },
    shipping: {},
  }
]

var newArray = originalArray.map(item => item.product);

console.log( newArray )
```

There's really no way to do it without iterating